# Android APP - Call Phone Number net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android

I have created a very simple APP with Android Studio that I use to load a website. In the website there are different entries from people who also leave their telephone number. When the APP is loaded and I click on the "Telephone" field, I get the error message: The website tel: 066653353 could not be loaded
**net :: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME**

Here is MainActivity.java file:

```
package name.work;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import name.work.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.mydomain.work");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {
                viewx.loadUrl(urlx);
                return false;
            }
        });

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack(); // Go to previous page
            return true;
        }
        // Use this as else part
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix this issue!
THANK YOU VERY MUCH :-)
Regards
shotput

Answer (score 1):

Inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method, you can check if url starts with `tel:` and open the device's dialer app like below:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {
if (urlx.startsWith("tel:")) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(urlx)); 
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
viewx.loadUrl(urlx);
return true;
```

}

Comment: Hallo Fahad! I tried your code. Sorry it dont work. If I click the "Phone" Button I get the error: the webpage at tel: 0xxxxxxxx could not be loaded because: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME regards shotput